# How to get a FASTA file onto my Debian 9 VM that I can only access through serial console on Azure

Tags: azure, file-upload, virtual-machine, debian-stretch

I am trying to upload a FASTA file to my Debian 9 (stretch) virtual machine. I can only access the VM via serial console on Azure portal. I'll be processing the file with a program called antiSMASH. I'll also need to somehow download the output file back to my computer.

Comment: What about the NSG rules for your VM and which ports need to open for the program antiSMASH?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what this means. I'm a pretty novice programmer.

Comment: The NSG just like a firewall for the traffic of the VM. So you need to expose the port through the rules.